# Организация авторизации андроид-приложения и бэкэнд части через google oauth2

Tags: php, android, google-oauth2

Есть андроид-приложение и есть серверная часть на php. Как реализовать авторизацию через google oauth 2, чтобы когда андроид-приложение запрашивало данные у серверной части, сервер знал, что это мое приложение и что это определенный авторизированный пользователь? Из документации google не совсем понял, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторизация на почти всех сервисах происходит почти одинаковым способом.

1. Юзер на клиенте открывает приложение или сайт сервиса.
2. Логинится там, если ещё не залогинен.
3. Сервис в зависимости от реализации перенаправляет юзера обратно в клиентское приложение, передав ему `access token` или `auth code` (в зависимости от типа авторизации). Перенаправление может быть как и прямо в `onActivityResult`, если для авторизации используется приложение сервиса или сервис передаёт `access token` или `auth code` в виде параметра страницы в браузере, если для авторизации используется он.
4. Клиентское приложение тем или иным образом получившее `access token` (в случае гугла это называется `id token`) или `auth code` отправляет его на сервер.
5. Сервер с помощью `access token` может от сервиса, через его API получить любую разрешённую юзером инфу. Обычно по умолчанию даётся доступ к ID юзера в сервисе, его фотографии, имени, часто `email`. Если изначально был получен `auth code`, то нужен дополнительный шаг - получить `access token` с помощью `auth code`, вызывав соответствующий метод API сервиса.
6. Чтобы всё это работало вам нужно будет всё это настроить на сайте сервиса, который вам даст `client id` и `client secret`, которые будут нужны для указания сервису что юзер именно в ваше клиентское приложение хочет залогиниться.

Comment: На счет 4 пункта. В андройд приложение приходит и аксес токен и id токен, id токен передается на сервер, и с сервера отправляется гуглу, гугл присылает ответом данные пользователя, но что использовать в качестве аксес токен между сервером и приложением.

Comment: И что делать когда срок аксес токена закончится, можно ли использовать как то рефреш токен? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @MaxKsam, в качестве `access token` лучше всего использовать собственную реализацию оного. Это необходимо для, например, возможности авторизации через разные сервисы. В этом случае сервер должен на клиент (после получения  `access token` сервиса) отправить собственный `access token`, который будет сгенерирован и сохранён в БД (в большинстве фреймфорков есть для этого возможности).

Comment: @MaxKsam, да, можно использовать `refresh token` сервиса, если он такой даёт и с его помощью обновлять `access token`. В серверной реализации `access token` также можно добавить `refresh token` и использовать его на клиенте для обновления `access token` сервера.